# Grammar structure of "你看，Sally 穿上传统服后有多漂亮“

Tags: grammar

```
你看，Sally 穿上传统服后有多漂亮.
```

My questions are

(1) Is Subject omitted? I think the sentence needs a Subject in "Sally 穿上传统服后 (Subject) 有多漂亮 ".

(2) If 后 is removed, how can I rewrite this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

你看 is a proclamation

Sally is the only subject in "Sally 穿上传统服后(她)有多漂亮." The pronoun '她'(she - referring to Sally)  is omitted. You don't need to repeat the subject in the single sentence

> "你看, Sally 穿上传统服后有多漂亮"
>
> Look! How pretty Sally looks after (she) put on a traditional dress.

if 后 is removed, the sentence would become "你看, Sally 穿上传统服有多漂亮"

> Look! How pretty Sally looks (when she) puts on a traditional dress.

Comment: Can I write "你看, 穿上传统服 Sally 有多漂亮"?

Comment: yes, you can write  "你看, 穿上传统服,  Sally 有多漂亮" putting the verb phrase before the subject to emphasize the action

Answer (score 2):

> (1) Is Subject omitted? I think the sentence needs a Subject in "Sally
>   穿上传统服后 (Subject) 有多漂亮 ".

No, Sally is subject. 穿上传统服后 used to modified Sally, 有多漂亮 is used to describe Sally 穿上传统服后.

> (2) If 后 is removed, how can I rewrite this sentence?

I would use traditional Chines to write since I cannot type simplified Chinese.

Simply write. 穿上傳統服的Sally有多漂亮。 I used 的 and things before 的(穿上傳統服) to modify Sally. So 有多漂亮 is used to describe 穿上傳統服的Sally.

Answer (score 2):

傳統服裝 is more native.

Not like English, Chinese adjectives can be predicate without linking verb(be verb).

So the structure is **Sally**(subject) **漂亮**(predicate)

e.g. 我很好.

穿上传统服裝后 is an adverbial clause.

有 is for comparing (with the clothes and without the clothes), but you have to use 有多 together, otherwise, it is ambiguous.

多 is another adverb modifies 漂亮 for emphasis, like 很.

These are all valid sentences for you to examine the structure.

Sally漂亮.

Sally多漂亮.

Sally有多漂亮. (Comparing Sally with others, but you can't say Sally有漂亮.)

Sally *穿上传统服裝后* 有多漂亮

---

Either and Both of the 后 and 上 can be removed, These are all ok.

Sally 穿传统服裝后 有多漂亮.

Sally 穿传统服裝 有多漂亮.

Sally 穿上传统服裝 有多漂亮.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's better to not have 后. As a native Chinese, I'd prefer to remove 上 as well.

On the other hand, we seldom say 传统服, it can be replaced by 传统服饰 or 传统服装。

Comment: So the sentence should be "Sally 穿传统服装有多漂亮"?

Comment: sounds far better than the original one.